# I want to move the listbox one to another listbox and update the particular listbox value

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, sql-server-2008

Here, Below i used the code. 
I am new in VBA.
I am trying to move the one list box to another listbox, but I am not able to update the database table. I am struggle on few days. Why this error came and how can i solve this problem. Can anyone please help me.

```
Dim varAdd As Variant
Dim strSQL As String

With lstFresh
    For varAdd = lstFresh.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
         If lstFresh.Selected(varAdd) Then
            strSQL = "UPDATE DatabaseMaintanence..UserMaster SET DatabaseMaintanence..UserMaster.usr_Team = '3' from DatabaseMaintanence..UserMaster inner join Infotronics..EmployeeGeneralMaster on (Status = 'W' and usr_Team = '1' and CampaignGroup like '%uk%survey%') and DatabaseMaintanence..UserMaster.usr_ReportName = " & varAdd & ""
Me.lstFresh.ItemData(varAdd) & "'"
            lstteamtwo.AddItem .List(varAdd)
            .RemoveItem varAdd
        End If
    Next varAdd

End With
```

Comment: Are you really using Postgres ***and*** SQL Server ***and*** MySQL all at the same time?

Comment: So, any errors? Or other description about _how_ it does not work?  And what role does VBA play here?  Does the query alone does what you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - no surprise there - many apps try to be all things to all men - "Yes, sir, of course, sir, we support your database of choice". Leads to least_common_denominator apps.

Comment: What is the double dot (..) syntax about? Unless the database part of this question is clarified, I'm going to vote to close - seems to be more VBA related to me and, as such, belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: You need to kink the sql-sever into (MS-Access or Excel) and use the linked table names in you VBA SQL?